How to make dropdown comments (answers) from FlatList item
I make news/articles using React Native.
I made a news layout (ViewLayout) - a news details page where comments are located in a FlatList.
I have a CommentCard - a component for rendering comments. I want to make replies to comments (nested comments), but I ran into a problem that I can't render them smoothly and now I doubt whether I'm moving in the right direction.
I have nested comments (replies) rendered in a CommentCard - a component for rendering main comments. I want a list of replies to drop down when I click on the "View replies" button.
Right now I have it done using LayoutAnimation and Animatable, but it's not pretty, the whole design jumps up (the selected comment), and the drop-down animation is wrong. I want the selected comment to stay in place and just drop down nested comments.
I looked to see if this could be done using collapsible and accordion. I tried to do it with react-native-collapsible, but it looked even worse (everything flickered for a few seconds), and I don't understand how to do it right with react-native-collapsible/accordion. Do I need to make it so that these nested comments are rendered specifically on the news layout (ViewLayout) and in the FlatList? How can I make this more efficient?
I've been sitting with this for a few days and am already confused.
The main condition is without using react-native-reanimated !!!
Gif where`s problem with rendering
This is "main layout", news details. Maybe i need to wrap comments in AnimationLayout or Collapsible here?
import React,{useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef} from 'react';
import { Redirect, router } from "expo-router"
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Linking, FlatList, RefreshControl,Animated } from 'react-native';
...

const ViewLayout = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { newsId} = route.params;
    const {user,setUser} = useGlobalContext();
    const { showAlert, alertData, showCustomAlert, hideCustomAlert } =useCustomAlert()
    const { newsData, comments, isLiked, isLikedComment, isLoading, setIsLiked, setIsLikedComment, refetch } = useNewsData(newsId,user.uid)

    .......

    //Logic for comments
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchCommentLikes = async () => {
        if (comments.length > 0) {
            const updatedComments = await Promise.all(
                comments.map(async (comment) => {
                    const isLiked = await checkIfLikedComment(user.uid, comment.$id);
                    return { ...comment, isLiked };
                })
            );
            setAllComments(updatedComments);
        }
     };

     fetchCommentLikes();
    }, [comments, user.uid]);


    const handleSendComment=async()=>{
      const text=inputValue.trim();
      if(text===''){
        return
      }
      else{
        try{
          setSendComment(true)
          await uploadComment(newsId,user,text);

          const newLocalComment = {
            $id: generateUniqueId(),
            user_name: user.name,
            user_login:user.login,
            date: formatDate(new Date()),
            text: text,
            likes: 0,
            numAnswers: 0,
            isLiked:false
        };
          setAllComments((prevComments) => [newLocalComment, ...prevComments]);
          setInputValue('');
        }catch(error){
          showCustomAlert({ title: "Упс", message: error.message });
        }finally{
          setSendComment(false);
        }
      }
    }
   
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-white flex-1">
      <FlatList 
        data={allComments}
        ref={flatListRef}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.$id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => ( //Main comments
          <CommentCard
            commentId={item.$id}
            username={item.user_name}
            creatorLogin={item.user_login}
            date={item.date}
            text={item.text}
            likes={item.likes}
            comments={item.numComments}
            commentsArray={item.answerArray}
            isLiked={item.isLiked}
            user={user}
            newsId={newsId}
            handleDelete={()=>handleDeleteComment(item.$id)}
            handleLike={()=>handleLikeComment(item.$id)}
          />
        )}
        ListHeaderComponent={() =>(

......
//Layout
)}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
        ListEmptyComponent={() => (
          <View className="pb-10">
            <EmptyState
              title="Коментарів немає"
              subtitle="Будь першим(-ою) хто опублікує коментар"
              textStyle="text-grey-600"
              comments
            />
          </View>
        )}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />

      {showAlert && (
                <CustomAlert
                    title={alertData.title}
                    text={alertData.message}
                    buttons={[{
                        title: 'Oк',
                        onPress: hideCustomAlert 
                    }]}
                    visible={showAlert}
                    onBackdropPress={hideCustomAlert}
                />
            )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default ViewLayout

This is comments card component where i render replies.
import { View, Text,Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, LayoutAnimation, UIManager, Platform, Animated} from 'react-native'
import React, { useState,useEffect,useRef } from 'react'
import { icons, images } from '../../constants'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';
.....

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

  
const CommentCard = ({
    commentId,
    newsId,
    image,
    username,
    creatorLogin,
    date,
    text,
    likes,
    comments,
    commentsArray,
    user,
    handleDelete,
    isLiked
}) => {
    const { showAlert, alertData, showCustomAlert, hideCustomAlert } =useCustomAlert()
    const dateText = useDateDiffString(date);
    const [likedState, setLikedState]=useState(isLiked)
    const [updateLikes, setUpdateLikes]=useState(likes || 0)
    const [updateNumComments, setNumComments]=useState(comments||0)
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false); 
    const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState(text);
    const [isAnswering, setIsAnswering]=useState(false);
    const [replyText,setReplyText]=useState('')
    const [isRepliesVisible, setIsRepliesVisible] = useState(false);
    const [replies, setReplies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (commentsArray) {
        const repliesArray = Object.entries(commentsArray).map(([id, reply]) => ({
          ...reply,
          id 
        }));
        setReplies(repliesArray);
      } else {
        setReplies([]); 
      }
    }, [commentsArray]);

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggleDropdown = () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };
    
    const handleLikeToggle = async () => {
        try {
            await userSetLikesComments(user.uid,newsId, commentId, likedState);

            setUpdateLikes(prevLikes => likedState ? prevLikes - 1 : prevLikes + 1);
            setLikedState(!likedState);
        } catch (error) {
            showCustomAlert({ title: 'Упс', message: 'Виникла помилка при обробці лайка' });
            console.error('Error handling comment like:', error);
        }
    }
    const handleEditComment = () => {
      setIsEditing(true);
    };
    const handleSaveComment=async()=>{
      try{

      }catch(error){
        showCustomAlert({ title: 'Упс', message: 'Виникла помилка при оновленні коментаря' });
      }finally{
        setIsEditing(false)
      }
    }

    const handleAnswering=()=>{
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
      setIsAnswering(!isAnswering)
    }

    const sendReply=async()=>{
      const text=replyText.trim()
      if(text==''){
        return
      }
      try{
        const newReply = await uploadReplyComment(newsId,commentId,user,text);
        console.log(newReply)
        setReplies(prevReplies => [newReply, ...prevReplies]);
        setNumComments(prevNum=>prevNum+1)
        setIsAnswering(false)
      }catch(error){
        showCustomAlert({ title: 'Упс', message: 'Виникла помилка при відправці коментаря' });
      }
    }

    const toggleReplies=async()=>{
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
      setIsRepliesVisible(!isRepliesVisible)
    }

    const deleteReply=async(id)=>{
      try{
        await deleteComment(newsId, id, true, commentId);
        setReplies((prevComments) => 
          prevComments.filter(comment => comment.$id !== id) 
        );
        setNumComments(prevNum=>prevNum-1)
      } catch (error) {
        showCustomAlert({ title: "Упс", message: "Помилка видалення коментаря. Спробуйте перезавантажити сторінку" });
     }
    }

// Function for rendering replies

    const renderReplies=()=>{
      return (
        <Animatable.View
          animation={isRepliesVisible ? "slideInDown" : "slideOutUp"} 
          duration={500} 
          easing="linear" 
          style={{ height: isRepliesVisible ? 'auto' : 0 ,overflow:'hidden' }} 
        >
          <View className="pl-10 mt-2">
            {replies.map((reply) => (
              <CommentCard
                key={reply.$id}
                commentId={reply.$id}
                newsId={newsId}
                username={reply.user_name}
                creatorLogin={reply.user_login}
                date={reply.date}
                text={reply.text}
                likes={reply.likes}
                comments={reply.numAnswers}
                user={user}
                handleDelete={() => {deleteReply(reply.id)}}
                isLiked={reply.isLiked}
                onReplyAdded={() => {}}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        </Animatable.View>
      );
    }
    const renderCommentField=()=>{
      return(
        <Animatable.View
        animation={isAnswering ? "slideInDown" : "slideOutUp"} 
        duration={500} 
        easing="linear" 
        style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }} 
        >
          <View className="pl-10 mt-2">
            <CommentField 
              otherStyles=""
              placeholder="Напишіть коментар..."
              contentStyle="w-auto"
              handleChangeText={(e)=>setReplyText(e)}
              onSend={sendReply}
            />
          </View>
        </Animatable.View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View className={`px-5 pb-4 relative`}>
        <View className="px-3 py-4 flex-col justify-center items-start border border-grey-border rounded-xl bg-white">
          <View className="flex-row justify-between items-start w-full pb-3">
            <View className="flex-row justify-between items-center">
              <Image
                source={images.avatar}
                resizeMode="contain"
                className="w-[40px] h-[40px] rounded-full"
              />
              <View className="flex-col justify-start items-start ml-2">
                <Text className="text-xs font-msemibold text-black-500">{username}</Text>
                <Text className="text-xs font-mlight text-black-500">{dateText}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
  
            <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-1">
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleLikeToggle}
              >
                <Icon 
                    name={likedState ? "heart" : "heart-o"} 
                    size={18} 
                    color={likedState ? "#F95757" : "#4E4E4E"}  
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text className="text-xs font-msemibold text-black-500">{updateLikes}</Text>
              {(user.login===creatorLogin || user.role==='ADMIN')&&(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleDropdown}>
                <Image
                  source={icons.dots_vertical}
                  className="w-[21px] h-[24px] mt-[-2px]"
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
          
          {isEditing?(
             <TextInput
              value={editedText}
              onChangeText={(e)=>setEditedText(e)}
              editable={true} 
              multiline={true}
              className="text-sm font-mmedium text-black-500 text-left"
           />
          ):(
            <Text className="text-sm font-mmedium text-black-500 text-left">{text}</Text>
          )}
          
          {/* Выпадающее меню */}
          {isOpen && (
            <View className="absolute right-0 top-10 bg-white shadow-lg shadow-black-500 rounded-lg py-3 pl-4 pr-12 z-10">
            
            {(user.login === creatorLogin) && (
              isEditing ? (
                <TouchableOpacity className="flex-row items-center"
                  onPress={handleSaveComment}
                >
                  <Image
                    source={icons.check}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    className="w-[30px] h-[32px] ml-[-3px]"
                  />
                  <Text className="ml-1 text-black-500 font-msemibold">Зберегти</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity className="flex-row items-center"
                  onPress={handleEditComment}
                >
                  <Image
                    source={icons.icon_pen}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    className="w-[30px] h-[32px] ml-[-3px]"
                  />
                  <Text className="ml-1 text-black-500 font-msemibold">Редагувати</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            )}
            <TouchableOpacity className="flex-row items-center mt-2"
                onPress={handleDelete}
            >
            <Image
                source={icons.icon_delete}
                resizeMode='contain'
                className="w-[20px] h-[24px]"
              />
              <Text className="ml-[10px] text-black-500 font-msemibold">Видалити</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
        <View className="mt-3 flex-row items-center w-full justify-between">
          {comments? (
            <SmallOutlinedButton
              containerStyles="border-primary-default min-h-[21px]"
              textStyles="text-grey-400"
              image={icons.arrow_down}
              imageStyles="w-[14px] h-[14px]"
              imageContainer="pr-2"
              title={isRepliesVisible ? "Сховати відповіді" : (updateNumComments ? `${updateNumComments} відповіді` : "Відповісти")}
              handlePress={toggleReplies} // Button 'View replies'
            />
          ) : (
          <View className="flex-grow" /> 
          )}

        <SmallOutlinedButton
          containerStyles="border-primary-default min-h-[21px]"
          textStyles="text-grey-400"
          title="Відповісти"
          handlePress={handleAnswering}
        />
      </View>
      
    </View>

    {isAnswering && renderCommentField()} 
      
    {isRepliesVisible && renderReplies()} //<---- Rendering replies here

    {showAlert && (
      <CustomAlert
        title={alertData.title}
        text={alertData.message}
        buttons={[{
          title: 'Oк',
          onPress: hideCustomAlert 
        }]}
        visible={showAlert}
        onBackdropPress={hideCustomAlert}
      />
    )}
    </View>
    );
  };
  
  export { CommentCard };

